# Mootools script not working in Camino/Firefox

Tags: firefox, dom, mootools, javascript

I currently have script that slides down a  once the page has loaded.

So far, it works in Safari, Opera and IE8, however it doesn't work in Camino nor Firefox, so I am guessing it's a Mozilla based problem with my code?

Here is my full file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEvent("domready", function() {

var trioSlide = $(triobanner);

trioSlide.setStyle('display','block');
trioSlide.fx = new Fx.Slide(trioSlide, {duration:1200});
trioSlide.fx.hide();
trioSlide.fx.toggle();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="triobanner" style="display:none;">
This should reveal itself
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you would like to see it in action, here it is. It works in Safari etc but not Firefox.

[Mooshell.net link](http://mooshell.net/6ZEH4/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently I forgot to place quote tags around $('triobanner');

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but are you really looking for STRICT document type which sometimes creates problems in different browsers.

Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Should be:

Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Hey there. Just tried it however don't think it's the problem, Firefox still doesn't load the slide in text.